# tkinter has no attribute named tk

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to learn tkinter however every time I import no matter what way it always says

```
module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk'
```

and this doesn't change no matter what import I use:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
```

The code i am trying to use which is failing is this:

```
root = tk.Tk()
my_gui = MyGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

and when I run python -m tkinter in the command line it opens a small window where it says that is is Tk version 8.6

How can I import it, as it always pops up with the same error. Thank you.

Comment: `Tk` is a function in the `tkinter` module, so access to it, following an `import tkinter as tk`, would be something like `root = tk.Tk()`.

Comment: Could you try `python -m tkinter`. Does it work?

Comment: Sorry, those two replies don't work

Comment: How did you install it, and what platform are you using?

Comment: I am using sublimer text editor 3 and running it using command line

Comment: @PeterOFN-Gaming try to run in terminal: `python -m tkinter` what you get in response?

Comment: ***"has no attribute `'Tk'`'"***: [Edit] your question and show a [mcve] to get this error message.

Comment: @PeterOFN-Gaming try: `from tkinter import Tk`

Comment: Is your python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi it is 3.x

Comment: @PeterOFN-Gaming what you get as response to above questions?

Comment: Did you name your script `tkinter.py`?

Comment: you dont need it to be called `tkinter.py`, it could be called anythin if you use this code: ```from tkinter import *``` then on another line:```root = Tk()```